# Node Id generation in storj

Tags: p2p, file-storage, dht, kademlia

How does NodeId generation in a storj kademlia node take place?
Why does it take long time to generate a nodeid and how does this contribute to the security of the node?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this blogpost](https://www.storj.io/blog/a-brief-overview-of-kademlia-and-its-use-in-various-decentralized-platforms) they require [hashcash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hashcash) when generating a nodeID, as proposed in the [S/Kademlia](https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.68.4986&rep=rep1&type=pdf) paper, to make make [sybil attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sybil_attack) more costly.